# Bootstrap autocomplete doesn't load the map

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, twitter-bootstrap, autocomplete

I have a map which is a JSON result. I need to assign it to autocomplete. But it seems like I have to do a dirty job. Is there any cleaner way to do that?

http://jsfiddle.net/7dLRh/

part of the code which is very dirty:

```
$( "#autocomplete1" ).autocomplete({

        source: function(request, response) {
            var re = $.ui.autocomplete.escapeRegex(request.term);                                   
            var matcher = new RegExp( "n*" + re + "n*", "i");   
            var arrayKey = $.map(v1.data, function (itemKey, itemValue) {
                return itemKey
            }); 
            var arrayValue = $.map(v1.data, function (itemKey, itemValue) {
                return itemValue
            }); 
            var key = $.grep( arrayKey, function(item,index){                                       
                return matcher.test(item);
            }); 
            var value = $.grep( arrayValue, function(item,index){                                       
                return matcher.test(item);
            }); 

            var s = "{ ";
            for (var i =0; i< key.length; i++) {
                if (i < value.length) {
                    s+= "\"" + value[i] + "\":\"" + key[i] + "\",";
                }                                       
            }       
            s = s.substring(0, s.length-1);
            s += "}";

            var jsonObject = jQuery.parseJSON(s);               

            response($.map(jsonObject, function (itemKey, itemValue) {
                return {
                    label: itemKey,
                    value: itemValue
                };
            }));
        }



    });
```

Comment: Doesn't `response(v1.data);` work? It seems to work for me, but maybe I'm misunderstanding

Comment: No it is not working because it is a map. I need it to be an array to make it work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

simply do this:

```
    var i = 0;
    var repCodesMap = v1.data;
    var repCodesSource = new Array();
    $.each(repCodesMap, function(key, value) {
        repCodesSource[i++] = { label : value, value : key };
    });

    $( "#autocomplete1" ).autocomplete({
        source : repCodesSource
    });
```

updated your code here:
http://jsfiddle.net/7dLRh/2/